# stop saving the excel when particular field is empty in Macbook

Tags: excel

I want create an excel file and in that excel, If a particular field (ex. A1) is empty , then the excel should throw warning and shouldn't allow the user save it.

How can i do this Excel in Macbook laptop

The user can only save the excel workbook , if he fills out the value in A1 filed.

Comment: vba with workbook events probably.

Comment: Hi Mike,
I am not sure about vba script, can you please point me to any links or notes on vba and workbook events.

Comment: Lots of q&a on here to check - some even have code you can edit.